# Pandas: Set values according to a list

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is like this:

```
a      b
0      123
0      321
0      456
12345  1234
43241  132
0      2134
12345  6543
43241  987
....
```

I need to set values in the third column according to a list (edit: `a` is not necessarily ordered):

```
a     0     12345 43241 ....
c     0     1     2     ....
```

so it should become

```
a      b     c
0      123   0
0      321   0
0      456   0
12345  1234  1
43241  132   2
0      2134  0
12345  6543  1
43241  987   2
....
```

Currently I'm doing this in a cycle:

```
a=data['a'].unique().tolist()
c=list(range(len(a)))
d=dict(zip(c,a))
df['c']=0
for i in d:
    df.loc[df['a']==d[i],'c']=i
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: I'll add this as a comment since it's been closed as a duplicate but I'm not sure it actually is. If the mapping value -> value is not just ranking but arbitrary (say, given by a dict) you can use apply. For example, if `d = {0: 0, 12345: 1, 43241: 2}`, then `df['c'] = df['a'].apply(lambda i: d[i])` gives what you want. EDIT: sorry I didn't see the second line in the provided code, indeed it suggests the mapping is not arbitrary but a ranking, so it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci Thank you wery much, I just forgot to notice that in my case ranking is not necessary, so your answer is to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['c'] = pd.factorize(df['a'])[0]

print(df)

       a     b  c
0      0   123  0
1      0   321  0
2      0   456  0
3  12345  1234  1
4  43241   132  2
5      0  2134  0
6  12345  6543  1
7  43241   987  2
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the list `a` is not ordered, for example, `a=[12345, 0, 43241]` and I want to set `c` according to this order?

Comment: @MichaelO., `pd.factorize` does not reorder by default. What do you need for your sample `a`, e.g. `[1, 0, 2]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think need set column to [`ordered categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) and then convert to [`cat.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html):

```
a = [12345, 0, 43241]

df['c'] = df.a.astype('category', ordered=True, categories=a).cat.codes
print (df)
       a     b  c
0      0   123  1
1      0   321  1
2      0   456  1
3  12345  1234  0
4  43241   132  2
5      0  2134  1
6  12345  6543  0
7  43241   987  2
```